# How do I parallelize a while loop processing a stack based depth first search with OpenMP?

Tags: c++, stack, openmp

I have a while loop like the following psuedo C++ code

```
stack.push(init.left);
stack.push(init.right);
while(!stack.empty) {
   t = stack.pop();
    if(foo(t)) {
        t->left = new node;
        t->right = new node;
        stack->push(t.left)
        stack->push(t.right)
    }
}
```

1. How should I prevent the loop from exiting prematurely if the stack is temporarily empty while other threads are calculating foo(t)? How do I know if the stack is actually empty? If I did this sequentially, it is only empty when it goes through all nodes.

I'm new to parallel programming and OpenMP, so bear with me :). I tried to enclose the entire loop with #pragma omp parallel private(t), but that seg faulted.

Comment: 1) You cannot parallelize your while loop as-is: you either need to use OpenMP tasks or convert the while loop into a for loop in canonical form. 2) The standard library is not thread-safe, so you need to surround each stdlib call inside your loop with `#pragma omp critical` to ensure only one thread executes it at a time. If you're using your own implementation instead of `std::stack`, you need to make it thread-safe yourself. 3) You must accept that the *order* of the threads popping and pushing can change from your current execution. Can your current algorithm properly handle this?